# Weird error on method in prototype from factory, stored in $scope in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I have really weird issue and i cant really think why this is happening on top of my head.

--------- **Factory**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('f_carousel', f_carousel);
f_carousel.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

function f_carousel($rootScope){

    // ---
    // Class ( Constructor )
    // ---

    function Carousel( totalSections ) {
        this.currentSection= 0;
        // All the initial variable for the constructor.
    }

    // ---
    // STATIC METHODS.
    // ---

    Carousel.load = function( totalSections ) {
        var carousel = new Carousel( totalSections );
        return( carousel );
    };

    // ---
    // INSTANCE METHODS.
    // ---

    Carousel.prototype = {

        // -------------
        // Public Methods
        // -------------

        // Click Event for the Next btn
        goNext: function goNext() {

            this.currentSection++;
            this.updateBtnVisibility();

        },
        // all other public & private methods below.
     }
     return ( Carousel );
  }
```

--------- **Controller**

```
app.controller('aboutMeCtrl', aboutMeCtrl);
    aboutMeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'f_carousel'];

    function aboutMeCtrl($scope, f_carousel){
        var carousel = f_carousel.load(3);
        $scope.currentSection = function(){
            return carousel.currentSection;
        };

        //This Works Fine.
        $scope.goNext = function(){
            carousel.goNext();
        };


        //This Doesnt Work.
        $scope.goNext = carousel.goNext;



    }
```

--------- **View**

```
<div class="m-slider__UI-arrow__icon" ng-click="goNext()"> Icon </div>
```

when I click on the Icon which has goNext() with ng-click in html, I get error message and the function do not work If I do this.

```
$scope.goNext = carousel.goNext;
```

goNext() cant access or trigger outside of its scope.

However this works fine.

```
$scope.goNext = function(){
     carousel.goNext();
};
```

> What is the best practice to map between methods and public variables from factory with $scope??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing `this` context, make it:

```
$scope.goNext = carousel.goNext.bind( carousel );
```

Inside `goNext` function `this` is not a Carousel instance anymore. It is an instance of your controller.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vb0dnrkf/

It is a best practice to do it like this

Comment: I got this now! Thank you @Gurami Dagundaridze

Answer (score 0):

While AngularJS is creating scope, carousel variable instance is not yet created so your $scope.goNext is initialized with undefined

```
$scope.goNext = carousel.goNext;
```

But when you click on icon and AngularJS calls callback, object is created so you are able to call that function.